# Issues with bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I am having several issues getting bxslider to work the way I am wanting. First and most importantly, it does not load unless I bring up the developers tools. I have no idea why this is the case.

I have all three of the js files on my page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

As well as the css page for bxslider.

My second issue is I can't figure out the DOM to get this style the way I am wanting. All I want to be able to do is controls the margins/padding between images and the top and bottom margins for this slider, to enable me to control the space around it.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
.slider4 {
    padding: 100px auto;
    border: none;
}
.bx-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.bx-viewport {
    width: 85%;
    border: none;
}
.slide {
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Comment: You have too much going on there, and `.slider4` is deep inside the services area. You should create a simple page with bx-slider then put that page in the same sub-domain as your site. Then embed an iframe of that page in your main page.

Comment: @zer00ne Are you referring to something like a php include file?

Comment: yes, on the surface, an iframe and include do the same thing, but I think an include has less restrictions.